# Add layout in method android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how can I create method to add linearlayout to other layout. I want to create method which when I use this method in activity, this method add linear layout in top of my activity layout. How can I do that?

Edit:
I do something like that:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        layout.addView(addNewLinearLayout(getApplicationContext()));

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    private View addNewLinearLayout(Context context) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        // Do something else here on your linear layout or to customize your linear layout
        return linearLayout;
    }

}
```

and this is xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

but my layout is not changing his color. Why?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, and why isn't is possibly with just creating a proper XML layout? You can basically add views simply with view.AddView()

Comment: create an new object of a LinearLayout and use addView method to the parent of the LinearLayout

Comment: I want to have method because I want to use that in others activities, so I want to have global method to add this view to every layout

Comment: Change your `linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));` to `linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
private View _addNewLinearLayout(context) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    // Do something else here on your linear layout or to customize your linear layout

    return linearLayout;
}
```

In the main you could call this like :

```
getView().addView(_addNewLinearLayout(context));
```

Comment: I use your way, but layout is still the same. Check my edits.

Comment: You would have to return in the method. Something like :

    return linearLayout;

Comment: Can you change the height to MATCH_PARENT ? since there is no content in the linearLayout and the height is WRAP_CONTENT, it wouldnt show anything.

Comment: now work. thank you. but How can I change gravity, because this added layout is bottom my main layout and I want to have thiss added layout in top

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24017/discussion-between-lokoko-and-user1302569)

Comment: I find the reason. I change LinearLayout on relative layout and now is in top

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a new LinearLayout like this:

```
LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

And then set it with:

```
setContentView(linLayout, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this sample method. You can add more parameters if you want.

```
public LinearLayout addLinearLayout(Context context) {
    LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

    //Add stuffs here, like LayoutParams

    return newLayout;
}

yourLinearLayoutName.addView(addLinearLayout(yourClassName.this));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View detailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourNewLayout, l_details, false);
```

where l_details is the instance of the Linear layout in which you want add another linear layout.